# Guava : setting the default Executor for ListenableFuture callbacks and listeners

Tags: java, guava, future

Our application has a number of services that implement `ListenableFuture`-based APIs, to the tune of:

```
public interface MyService {
    ListenableFuture<Thing> getMyThing();
    ListenableFuture<?> putMyThing(Thing thing);
}
```

As our domain model is not at all thread-safe, we run most of our code, except for the aforementioned services, on a well-known single-thread `Executor`. I think it would be nice if the services could guarantee that any listener added to the `Future`s they produce will be called on that `Executor`.

Of course, I could very well enforce this in the services' clients, by calling `ListenableFuture.addListener`, `Futures.addCallback` or `Futures.transform` with the appropriate `Executor` argument but what I'm aiming at is precisely reducing the complexity and possibility of errors in the client code, so I would like the listener calls to happen on the well-known `Executor` when those methods are called without passing an `Executor` argument.

So, for now I've been implementing the services' methods this way:

```
class MyServiceImpl {
    private Executor executor; /* the "main" executor */

    public ListenableFuture<Thing> getMyThing() {
        ListenableFuture<Thing> future = ...; /* actual service call */

        return Futures.transform(future, Functions.<Thing>identity(), executor );
    }
}
```

First, does this even work? From the Guava source, it seems that it does, but I would be glad for some kind of confirmation, and I'm having a bit of a hard time thinking about unit testing this.

Moreover, I'm a bit worried about the usefulness/cost ratio of the whole "Service calls back on specified thread (by default)" pattern. Does anyone have experience with something like this? Are there any hidden pitfalls in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed `identity()` solution should work -- with two exceptions.

Proof: First, notice that the only reasonable way for `Futures.transform` to learn when its input is done is through a call to `input.addListener()`. We know that `addListener()` respects the given executor. (If you don't believe me: `ListenableFutureTask` uses `ExecutionList`, which invokes listeners in only two places: `add()` and `execute()`. In both places, it uses the given executor.) Thus, any task run at the time that the input `Future` completes will run in the given executor.

The key phrase here is "run at the time that the input `Future` completes." The exceptions:

- If someone adds a listener after the `Future` is complete, it will run in the thread that calls `addListener`.
- If someone cancels the wrapper `Future` (as opposed to the original), the listeners will run in the thread that calls `cancel`.

Depending on how your application is structured, these exceptions might be OK, but they're something to keep in mind. If they are a problem, you may want to use a `ForwardingListenableFuture` solution (like eneveu's but apparently less strict).

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you have all your methods return a `ListenableFuture` wrapper like:

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

public class ListenableFutureWithFixedExecutor<V> extends ForwardingListenableFuture<V> {

    @Nonnull
    private final ListenableFuture<V> delegate;
    @Nonnull
    private final Executor executor;

    public ListenableFutureWithFixedExecutor(@Nonnull ListenableFuture<V> delegate, @Nonnull Executor executor) {
        this.delegate = checkNotNull(delegate);
        this.executor = checkNotNull(executor);
    }

    @Override
    protected ListenableFuture<V> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(Runnable listener, Executor executor) {
        checkArgument(this.executor.equals(executor), "Listeners can only be executed using %s", executor);
        super.addListener(listener, executor);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}
```

Another possibility: instead of throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` when the client calls `addListener()` with an incorrect callback, you could simply log a warning, and call `super.addListener()` with the correct executor.

You could even add a method `<V> void addCallback(FutureCallback<? super V> callback)` that adds the given callback to the Future, using the fixed executor. This would let you use your Future more fluently :)

Comment: Thank you, maybe I've not been as clear as I should have been, but my purpose is not to _forbid_ the client code from using another Executor to run callbacks, it is just to avoid errors should someone forget to use the appropriate Executor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a pitfall in the following way: listeners will execute on `sameThreadExecutor()`, which means they will execute in *all the same thread* on the executor, not spreading out between threads in the same executor like they probably should.

I don't believe there's going to be a convenient way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: My "exit" `Executor` actually has one thread, so that's not an issue here - it's actually a goal. Thanks for the heads up nevertheless, I had not thought about that.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about this, I'm not even sure that it's an issue if the Executor has a thread pool, as the execute() of sameThreadExecutor is called from a Thread that was chosen by the executor passed to Futures.transform : unless I'm mistaken, with the line `input.addListener(output, executor);` in `Futures.transform`, `output.run()` is called upon completion of `input` on a Thread selected by the executor, and from there it's all on the same thread.